# Open torrent file in uTorrent with C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io, bittorrent

I am creating a windows service in C# .net. In the service i have a FileSystemWatcher that checks a directory (which is in my dropbox) for the create event for files. No problems so far. The idea is that I watch for the creation of torrent files. Then when a torrent file is created in that directory, I want to add it to uTorrent and start the download.

The windows service, file system watcher, no problem at all. My only question is: how to add the torrent to uTorrent (or an other torrent client), or, how to download the torrent in C#?

I hope I made my self clear :-)

Comment: can't you configure uTorrent to automatically load and start torrents it finds in a particular directory.  I know you can with other clients, like Vuze

Comment: @San: You can do that with uTorrent as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of 'wrapper' libraries for the uTorrent JSON API which you can manipulate uTorrent with!

I do not know what functionality other clients offer as far as remote control goes. Command line, undoubtedly.

Comment: thanks! I found it! for others that were looking for this, take a look at this site: http://utorrentclient.codeplex.com/

Comment: Do not forget to accept either abatishchev, my or someone else's answer. See the FAQ if you have questions on how to do it!

Answer (score 4):

To start default BitTorrent client:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;

string dirWithTorrent = @"c:\Downloads";

Process.Start(Path.Combine(dirWithTorrent, "example.torrent"));
```

Comment: Right, i knew that one, but i have to prevent for pup up messageboxes and stuff in uTorrent. So maybe somebody know a way to start the download silently? or maybe there is some kind of torrent client that provides a litle API? thanks anyway!

Comment: @Vincent: Each client has its own, specific settings and command-line arguments for silent download. So you need to start uTorrent by exactly well-known path.

Comment: @Vincent: Also uTorrent has it's own directory watching feature to monitor and silent download. Just configure it and put files there

Comment: @Vincent: Anyway, use existing, full-reach client; don't write your own